# HQL Query Based on Set Contents

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a hibernate managed POJO with a set:

```
public class Book {
    private Set<Page> pages;
    public Set<Page> getPages() { return pages; }
    public void setPages(Set<Page> pages) { this.pages = pages; }
}
public class Page {
    private int pageNumber;
    public int getPageNumber() { return pageNumber; }
    public void setPageNumber(int pageNumber) { this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
}
```

How would I write a HQL query based on the page number? For example, return all books that have a pageNumber greater than 100?

The following does not work:

```
from Book where pages.pageNumber > 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join`:

```
select distinct b from Book b join b.pages p where p.pageNumber > 100
```

Without `distinct` it would return a separate instance of `Book` for each page satisfying the condition.

**See also:**

- [16.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

Answer (score 0):

using implicit join

> from Book b where b.pages.pageNumber >
>   100

This one is easier

Comment: As far as I remember, it doesn't work for collection-valued properties.

Comment: have you try it yet axtavt? It used to work for me. try it if not tell me to update my knowledge.